# Print XYZ layer with MapFish Print plugin

Tags: printing, tile-map-service, xyz

I have a XYZ layer(i hope i call it right) in GeoExt/gxp application:

```
,{source: "ol",group: "background",fixed: true,type: "OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ",args:   
["ЕЭКО","http://maps.rosreestr.ru/ArcGIS/rest/services/BaseMaps/BaseMapAnno/MapServer/tile/$\{z\}/$\{y\}/$\{x\}",{visibility: true}]}
```

In MapFish documentation says that print plugin can print TMS and Tile Cache. But its print only WMS layers. I gonna set url to XYZ layer or something?

**UPDATE**

I found working XYZ print in here http://map.geo.admin.ch/. But There is something strange with layer which set to print.

**UPDATE2**

More interesting that GeoExt.PrintProvider not send XYZ layer to print plugin. But if i give to it gwc layer i can see gwc layer to post parameters:
[image]

But this layer not print.

Why PrintProvider not send XYZ layer in post parameters?